# Azure Data Factory Entities Dependencies Finding

Tags: azure-data-factory

How do we find out the dependencies between various ADF entities such as Pipelines, Datasets & Linked Service?

**Example**: I have one dataset DS_ASQL_DB. How do we check if this dataset is being used/referred to in any ADF pipelines?

Answer (score 5):

In the ADF UI, we can click the entity and see the **Related** tab.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked it and it is working fine. Do we have similar options available for finding Linked Service Dependencies ?

Comment: Sorry, Linked Service Dependencies seem different. We cann't see the used/referred entities.